# Convert 6.5e-7 to a formatted number such as 0.00000060

Tags: php, numbers

I have a number that is pulled from an API that displays as 6.5e-7, I would like to display this as 0.00000060 (I think this is what 6.5e-7 means),

I have tried to get this correct using the php ROUND function but it will only show as 0 or 6.5e-7 when I used a precision.

```
print round($vSat, 8);
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, I would think you need to do a formatted print which is printf

```
printf ("%.8f", $vSat)
```

%.8f  means floating point and 8 decimal places

https://www.php.net/printf

Answer (score 0):

Use printf/sprintf formatting.

printf("%10.10f", $yournumber);